# Is there a way to identify objects at all external lighting conditions

Tags: python, opencv

Do we have any algorithm/methodology in opencv through which I can identify object regardless of how dark or bright the sun is. 
I know this might be an old problem to all the people who have been working on image processing.

I have been trying to identify RGB colors using the HSV range, the problem is the ranges that work in the morning does not seem to work efficiently in the afternoon or if its cloudy or sunny (in short when the external lighting condition changes). Atleast, one of the colors fail to identify at some point of the day. So I have not been able to make my program stable with one set of values to the RGB colors.

Apparently these values works in the evening

```
lower = {'red': (0, 70, 50), 'green': (30, 28, 50), 'blue': (90, 25, 21)} 
upper = {'red': (7, 255, 255), 'green': (85, 255, 255), 'blue': (230, 255,255)}
```

while in the afternoon it is,

```
lower = {'red': (0, 70, 50), 'green': (40, 28, 50), 'blue': (97, 25, 30)}  
upper = {'red': (5, 255, 255), 'green': (85, 255, 255), 'blue': (230, 255, 255)}
```

And this is the part of the code where I do Image processing,

```
frame = cv2.imread('picture.png')

blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(frame, (7, 7), 0)
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(blurred, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV_FULL)

    kernel = np.ones((5, 5), np.uint8)
    mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower[key], upper[key])
    print(lower[key])
    print(upper[key])
    mask = cv2.morphologyEx(mask, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)
    mask = cv2.morphologyEx(mask, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
    # find contours in the mask and initialize the current
    # (x, y) center of the ball
    _, cnts, _ = cv2.findContours(mask.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,
                            cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    cv2.drawContours(frame, cnts, -1, (0, 255, 255), 1)
    if len(cnts) > 0:
        c = max(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea)
        ((x, y), radius) = cv2.minEnclosingCircle(c)
        if radius < 250:
            cv2.circle(frame, (int(x), int(y)), int(radius)
            cv2.putText(frame, key + " dice", (int(x - radius), int(y - radius)), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1.0,
                        colors[key], 2)
            cv2.imshow("Frame", frame)
```

I would like to know if there is any better way to do the processing of the image with constant values so I can identify the colors of RGB. Currently it works but it is not stable, I can't rely on the program to work at all conditions.I would like to know how in real time one solves this problem.

Comment: You could try converting to greyscale, finding image gradients, and determining objects from that?

Comment: Are you trying to detect dice? Template matching is the best method for detecting dice.

Comment: Yeah I could do that, but at the end I want the program to say the color of the dice. So I am not converting the image to greyscale. Actually I use a robot arm, eventually based on the RGB color the Robot sorts the dices.

Comment: @StephenMeschke yes, I am detecting the dice and sort based on the color(RGB). Thank you very much for your suggestion I will look into Template matching.

Comment: For a completely different direction: you could add some LED's / a light to the robot arm and have it shine at the dice before processing. That way the lighting conditions are more similar